# Woocommerce checkout: Update cost OR update total price via "update_checkout" ajax event

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

So, i trigger `update_checkout` via javascript. Then, i have function to be called in `woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping` hook. The function is to add/remove `free_shipping` shipping method (it's based on *Cash on Delivery* availability).

There are two radio buttons of payment method:

- Direct Transfer
- Cash on Delivery

The script already works. So when i choose COD (Cash on Delivery), the free shipping method is selected automatically.

But, the problem is **the total price did not changed, this indicates that the cost is still available**. Well, it changed, but it is late. I said late because the total price is canged when i change the payment method by choosing *Direct Bank Transfer* radio button.

The question is,

1. why the total price doesn't update realtime when the payment method is changed? Ok, it changed but in the next change event.
2. what is WooCommerce API to update the total price OR to update the cost? Where in the hook should i place this?

:) Thank you very much for answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [this](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_AJAX.html#245-391) function in WC_AJAX:

```
public static function update_order_review(){
}
```

By calling:

```
WC_AJAX::checkout();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering @Robin Pedersen , think i found the problem.
It is fix now, i'll answer this question if i am able to

But another issue is found, maybe i'll make another question too

Answer (score 0):

Those two functions from WC API should help.

**calculate_totals()** and **calculate_shipping()**.

```
global $woocommerce;

$woocommerce->cart->calculate_totals();
$woocommerce->cart->calculate_shipping();
```